# How do you authenticate a Wordpress front-end against a RESTful Grails-driven backend?

Tags: php, web-services, wordpress, rest, grails

I'm developing a Software as a Service offering that other developers can use to integrate into their own sites running on Wordpress (and eventually other platforms). The backend will run on a set of REST webservices using Grails.

I want to create a set of Wordpress widgets that can automatically hook in to my web services. The wordpress installation will manage all of the content, but the Grails backend will manage all of the application and domain logic, including user management.

I think I understand how I will get basic stateless calls from Wordpress to Grails to work by passing back JSON or XML structures and then parsing and displaying those in PHP. But beyond that, I'd like to support stateful activity as well, like allowing users to fill out a login form on a Wordpress site, yet authenticating them against the Grails backend. After the user is logged in, their credentials (or session) should continue to propagate for future webservice calls.

I'm not quite sure how to get started since I'm relatively new to web services, and have never done webservice or cross-site security . One idea that I had was to somehow expose a Java jsessionid to the client, but I'm not sure how exactly to do that.

Are there any patterns or preferred models for this type of setup? Has anybody done a similar type of integration that could give me some guidance?

Comment: This related question has some good ideas that I'm looking into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453551/rest-user-authentication

Comment: I looked into OAuth a little bit, and it doesn't seem like the solution I want because the workflow would want to send the user to a page on my site to authenticate. I want the user to think they're logging into my clients' sites, but I'm just managing all of the authentication/authorization through the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might try using the grails plugin on the back-end which supports AJAX authentication.

http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Ajax+Authentication

Comment: This is interesting, but since its all in one app, the view still has access to the session to see if the user is logged in. The problem that I'm facing is more on Wordpress side. Do I keep a wordpress session, store a hashed username/password and just send it to the API on every request? I think that's the direction I'm leaning. Just trying to gather more ideas before I move forward with an implementation.

Comment: you could create a cookie that has an authentication token that is shared between wordpress and the application

Comment: OK, that's what I'm probably going to do. Thanks for the advice. I'll let you know how it goes in the next few weeks when I get around to actually trying to implement it. :)