# Rest API and UserSign - Correct endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, api, rest

I'm planning to make a WCF rest api but I am confused about something.

I get how a rest api would work for getting or registering a user...

GetUser

```
GET
/user/username
```

Register user

```
POST
/user
[POST DETAILS]
```

What I don't get is user sign in. Logically it should be on the 'User' endpoint but it doesn't really work with the CRUD model.

Should it just be on it's own /login endpoint? And if so, should it be a GET or POST?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I implement login in a RESTful web service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608225/how-do-i-implement-login-in-a-restful-web-service)

Comment: The question seems different to be. Plus, the answers to that question were more abstract to what I wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be on a `/login` endpoint:

```
POST /login
[CREDENTIALS]
```

Comment: "POST" would be the recommended way to go as "GET" would send the username/password in the url.

Comment: @muruge, for this reason HTTPS should always be used. In this case it doesn't really matter whether you are using GET or POST. It's just that POST is more appropriate for logging in as it potentially modifies state on the server.