# Several logins in RESTFUL API

Tags: java, spring, rest, restful-authentication, spring-integration

We are designing a RESTFUL API that needs to support several login services.

```
Custom login:  ptgapi/v1/clients/{clientId}/users?mode=custom
FB login:      ptgapi/v1/clients/{clientId}/users?mode=facebook
Twitter login: ptgapi/v1/clients/{clientId}/users?mode=twitter
LinkedIn login: ptgapi/v1/clients/{clientId}/users?mode=linkedin
Create user:   ptgapi/v1/clients/{clientId}/users
```

We have an Spring Integration layer in top of the services, so in based of the provided path, one of the services will need to be activated.

The idea would be to have a router that catches the inbound-gateway input and redirect the flow based on the payload value.

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="v1.login.inbound.gateway" path="/ptgapi/{apiVersion}/clients/{clientId}/users" .../>
```

But here 'create user' has the same routing process than the other ones...and I think this is a bad smell.

Is a better approach to obtain it with a better separation of concerns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services may have the same path/route but they are identified by the operation. In REST you will have same path for services but depending on the kind of operation you are doing the HTTP method will  be different. You can differentiate your login and create services by using POST and PUT HTTP methods.

Personally speaking, I believe PUT is a better choice because PUT gives more control such as :

- Do you name your URL objects you create explicitly, or let the server decide? If you name them then use PUT. If you let the server decide then use POST.
- PUT is idempotent, so if you PUT an object twice, it has no effect. This is a nice property, so I would use PUT when possible.
- You can update or create a resource with PUT with the same object URL

More on PUT versus POST

**PUT** implies putting a resource - completely replacing whatever is available at the given URL with a different thing. By definition, a PUT is idempotent. Do it as many times as you like, and the result is the same. x=5 is idempotent. You can PUT a resource whether it previously exists, or not (eg, to Create, or to Update)!

**POST** updates a resource, adds a subsidiary resource, or causes a change. A POST is not idempotent, in the way that x++ is not idempotent.

Comment: Do you mean using PUT in the login (because the token is modified) and POST in the creation?

Comment: @antacerod No i was thinking other way around. PUT for creating the entity and POST for login. I am sharing few SO links to support that :-)

Comment: OK. I see your point...I was wrong with the concepts I had about REST. I will follow your advices. Thanks and good answer!

Answer (score 1):

For the user CRUD you should have a route like ***ptgapi/v1/clients/{clientId}/users*** and use the HTTP methods as they are supposed to: ***GET*** for returning the user, ***PUT*** for creating the user, ***POST*** for updating the user and ***DELETE*** to remove it.

The login operation is not a user entity operation per se. You should have another route, just like ***ptgapi/v1/clients/login*** and pass the login parameters via POST (encrypted preferably).

Comment: Thanks Alexander. This is a good option to differentiate login from creation. I will kept it in mind!

Comment: REST authentication is an open debate. There's no written in stone best practice. Keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Create user is an action so maybe you can define a new route like

```
Create user:   ptgapi/v1/clients/{clientId}/users/new
```

or something like this.

Comment: I have thinking on it but from an strict restify point of view, the operation of creating a new user must be the one I have told in the post... Aren't you think the problem is more related to the login paths instead of the create user?

Comment: For this design I have followed the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608225/how-do-i-implement-login-in-a-restful-web-service

Comment: Simple question: the "create user" is creating a user for a specific service or is a general one (for the specified client) ?

Comment: Is a general one because will be used in several services. Why did you ask it?