# Authentication in Apache Jersey without using Http-Authentication?

Tags: java, authentication, rest, jersey, restful-authentication

I am building a RESTful Webservice using Apache Jersey. Now I want that you need an authentication for some requests to it. Using the typical REST-approach the Authentication should be done via HTTP-Authentication. But a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication)  mentions that a better way how this can be done is by using cookies. I think there are some valid points in the discussion. (How) Can I make my Jersey Authentication work with Cookies? Do I need another framework for it?

Answer (score 6):

Jersey uses the authentication mechanism declared in the enclosing web application's web.xml, practically either HTTP Authentication (over SSL) or Form-based Cookie authentication.

If you want to used cookie-based session authentication, users must authenticate with the web service first to create a session which can be used to check their identity for future calls. The servlet spec provides a standardized way to authenticate using cookies and session using a web form, which however, is not compatible to a web service type of application. So you would probably want to cook up some custom solution to let users submit their credentials via POSTing an XML or JSON document. A problem with this method is that if a user performs a call to a resource without first authenticating or after the session has expired, they will need to be redirected or receive some type of error code. Not impossible but it adds complexity to your web service.

At this point you have to wonder if using HTTP Auth is not the better choice for web service style apps. We recently built a web service using Jersey and HTTP Auth as the authentication mechanism. We then build a Javascript front end on top of it. The Javascript client always submits the Authentication headers to the web service so that the user is never confronted with the HTTP Auth authentication window from the browser. Perhaps the best of both worlds.