# how to secure my java REST API

Tags: java, rest, security

I have a REST API in java that displays some confidential data.
Now, even if i use an auth token, if some one has a proxy installed can see that data i.e., the client-Id etc that is used to get the auth token, and then use the auth token to hit the REST API.

Is there a way to prevent this.

Comment: What about using SSL? It would ensure that the communication doesn't allow a middle-man attack

Comment: i guess we can download the certificate and add it to the proxy client.? can't we?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238094/securing-rest-api-without-reinventing-the-wheel