# restful authentication using php

Tags: php, oracle, restful-authentication, weblogic-10.x

I have a restful webservice made using oracle weblogic server. which converts siebel data in restful format. But when authentication from oracle weblogic activated, i m trying to call that web service it first ask user name and password of register user. Now I would like to trap that though php. I do have user name and password of users but how to pass data and place authentication I m understudying, Please let me know, how can we pass username and password parameters and check is there any session available or not?

I have used CURL for access webservice, when authentication disabled, I can able to access data.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an "Authorization" header to your WS call. see http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Authentification (Basic auth)