# GWT + Spring Services + Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, gwt, spring-security

I've a small architecture as follows :

- Client-App (using GWT)
- RESTful-services (using Spring)

Client can communicate with services through *ProxyServlet* to avoid 'Same-Origin-Policy' because they were deployed as different applications (WAR)

The RESTful-services were secured using Spring-Security, and also the Client-App

The question is, how to sign-in in one application (say client), and use that session to make calls on the other app?

Comment: GWT calls are basically HTTP requests. So if you authenticate your HTTP requests once with Spring Security it should also apply to any call made from the GWT client side.

Comment: But the 2 different apps deployed on 2 different servers, and the granted ticket were granted for one of them (as a Cookie), not both.

is there a way to make Proxy with form authentication or something like that?

Comment: ok however a true restful service should be stateless and thus there shouldn't be a session cookie. I guess you can use some proxy settings to pass on the authentication cookie. However also try to look into ["true" restful authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication).