# how to authenticate the drupal7 webservice which i am calling in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, authentication, drupal-7

In drupal7 i have created on rest web service using services module.
 I am calling this web service in my excel through visual studio 2010 and i am successful in calling it to. 
But what i want is that when i call this web service in vs 2010 1st it must ask for your username and password and this must get authenticate on my website  from my user table. 
But currently i am unable to implement this. any idea how to apply authentication on this ?
i want to know that is there any other module which can perform this or i have to write code for that.

Comment: Your requirement is quite similar to what has been answered by op in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119127/signing-into-drupal-website-remotly-using-c-net-and-json/16126533#16126533