# What exactly application of RESTful web services?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am developing a Java application where 2 Java applications communicate each other to share data between them.
I wrote code for a RESTful webservice and shared data. But my problem is while doing this all data is visible publicly means any application can put that Uri and get full data. So is there any secure way to do so?
And what is exactly purpose of RESTful webservices?

Comment: I guess you're asking about authentication in REST. If so, improve your question, and look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/319530/1089062

Comment: @WIll right what i was asking is somewhat related to that question (so thnx), but not exactly what i was asking.

Comment: @suku In that case, could you please edit your question to clarify how your it's different? It's likely to be closed as a duplicate if you don't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly is RESTful programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

Comment: @RobWatts thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is basically used for sharing data and fastest way to send and receive data between two application

in order to use effectively you need to have certain way of encryption and key sharing mechanism implemented

try to see this one
http://www.keyczar.org/

@suku in brief we used to develop CRUD (collect record update delete) commends to store and retrieval of information using HTTP GET or POST commands to server side program,

and depending on the context we decide which of CRUD command executed to the database.

why restful framework is good in sharing data between two system is they only need to expose that 4 basic commands to sync or share what they want to share

by make use of HTTP commands (GEt POST PUT and DELETE) same as CRUD operations.

[FYI About HTTP Commands](http://papa.det.uvigo.es/%7Etheiere/cursos/Curso_WWW/codes.html)

i think purpose is mainly for exchanging data between systems in more light weight way.not like web services which need extra processing power to parse XML to serialize to local interface to become object in memory before saving.

so restful technique is used when

> such very structural and accurate representation of object is not needed in between the system, both system exchanging make use of the raw data only instead of serialized object.
>
> and when two system exchanging data need to make use of the data only and when not need to have same structural representation of object attributes and relationships used in object oriented programming. ( but still can use serialized object transfers between the systems )
> NOTE : each system must very sure what they are exchanging is meaningful.

hope this help answer your questions.

Comment: Yes that link was helpfull :),but what is idea behind this RESTfull , do u know any history related to invention of this RESTfull?

Comment: @suku The link in the last comment of your question should give you all the info you need.

Comment: @takendarkk thanks :-)