# Building a restful api

Tags: php, api, authentication, restful-authentication

I am in the process of making a restful API for a product that I work on. But I dive head first, I would like to double check a few details.

**Authentication**

Authentication is done on the API side of the system, the client sends a username and password  to the server (API) and the API responds with either a token, or an exception does that sound correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think its ok, but i suggest you check this out :

https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link I like the look of oAuth2 but I understanding is that it is used for intergration of 3rd party logins (like logging into stackexchange from a google account). Can I use oauth2 to use my own authentication methods?

Comment: The fastest way is just to modify the simple-autentiation class, to instead of a json fetch the users from the database. Search for :  ** public function verify()** in the SimpleAuth.php file

Comment: Also here is a useful tutorial again with oAuth

http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/securing-php-rest-api-oauth/