# How to authenticate Zend Framework 1 users to access Laravel 5 API?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, zend-framework, authorization

need your ideas.

I have a ZF1/Postgres application. It has its own users and all that.
Now I would like the whole application to be API-driven. I started to build
RESTful resources in a new Laravel 5 application. The Laravel app will talk to the same Postgres DB. Eventually, I want to get rid of all the DB calls within the ZF1 app, so that Laravel app is in charge of that.

The question is: I would like to add authorization for each API call, so that I know which users produce those calls and could act accordingly. What is the best way to authenticate users, so they could access Laravel endpoints?

Comment: Who will use the API? Internal, trusted or untrusted third parties?

Comment: @dschniepp This is an internal API. For example, when user updates his profile data, I do want to do an API call from ZF1 controller to Laravel 5 endpoint. Bu in order to do something like POST /profile, I first need to authenticate the user, so that application know which user to operate with

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use RFC-standard oAuth2 authentication, I would go with https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

Assuming you do, you'd probably want to use the "password" grant-type for internal authentication.  Your client would hit the **/oauth/access_token** endpoint for a token using the user's username and password, which would return an access token good for the rest of the API.

To protect a route, you'd put it in the Route::group(['before' => 'oauth']...) section. To access an oauth-protected endpoint, you'd put the token in the HTTP header "authorization": "bearer ".

If you aren't using the standard laravel Users model, you may have to do a little tweaking.  Most of it is covered in the oauth plugin wiki.

Answer (score 0):

If the API is not public and there isn't any change to access it directly from the internet I wouldn't use any authentication. I would pass the userId in a custom http-header and and authenticate via `Auth::loginUsingId(1)` this will be *cheaper* then doing real authentication stuff. Therefore you have to map `App\User` to your existing user-table.

If you want to do *real* authentication take a look at [RESTful Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication)

For inspiration on how to use Laravel for a REST-Service take a look at the [dingo/api](https://github.com/dingo/api) package (currently only Laravel 4, 5 is in progress).