# Check website authentication mode

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

Okay, so I've got a website. It's a site, where I can check my university timetable. So I've decided to write an application in Python, which logs in, scraps the timetable (classrooms, hours, lecturers, etc.), and display them, lets say for the beggining, in a .txt file. So I've done some Basic Authentication with `HTTP Requests`, it looked just like this:

```
url = "http://httpbin.org"
authURL = "http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd"
r=requests.get(authURL, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("user", "passwd"))
print (r.content)
```

It's a freely hosted service, just to practise. Okay, but there are many other types of authentication. And here's my question: How can I actually determine which one is this website using, and then use that information in my application?

Comment: The first answer in this link provided a list of common authentication methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication