# How to provide authenticated REST access to third parties?

Tags: rest, restful-authentication

What is a good way to provide access to a datastore where other  applications can store their data ? We are thinking of a REST service but I am not sure about how to provide authentication. This is in java and will be jax-rs. 
But I am not sure what the best way to authenticate them will be. What are the common patterns for this kind of a problem ?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication

Comment: I did see that- its a rather old question. Despite the voluminous answers, none of them mention client certificates and some answers are wrong. I am looking for a more comprehensive, recent take on the matter