# Restfull API organising endpoints

Tags: rest, api, restful-url

I am trying to organise the endpoints of restfull api which we are building. What I have so far is:

```
GET - /api/members/list

GET - /api/members/:member_id
PUT - /api/members/:member_id
DELETE - /api/members/:member_id
POST - /api/members - add member

POST - /api/member/forgot_password
POST - /api/member/reset_password
POST - /api/member/sign_up - this is same as - POST - /api/members - add member
POST - /api/member/sign_in 
POST - /api/member/validate

POST - /api/member/auth/twitter
POST - /api/member/auth/gplus
POST - /api/member/auth/facebook
```

The thing is that I am not sure about

```
POST - /api/members/forgot_password
OR
POST - /api/member/forgot_password

//For register a member to use post over resource
POST - /api/members
OR
//To have endpoit for that
POST - /api/member/sign_up
```

so the what I understand about restfull concept is to use the request verbs over a resource. But how this apply when we have `/api/members` resource and I would like to have an endpoint for login a member?

`/api/members/sign_in` or `/api/sign_in` or `/api/member/sign_in`

Comment: What do you think "sign in" means in a RESTful API? What auth schema are you using?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't think in a RESTful `sign in` can be considered as resource. It's a more like functional thing, if I am correct. Not really understand what you mean by auth schema, my login works like this: member provides email and password, then JWT is created. I would have login with facebook as well which would work like this: it will require a valid fb access_token then will create JWT same as the sign in function.

Answer (score 1):

To me, using plural or singular nouns is a matter of teaste.

`GET /api/members` should reasonably return a collection of members while to get one is perfectly meaningful to use either

`GET /api/members/{id}` or

`GET /api/member/{id}`.

So, if your concern about the `forgot_password` resource was about the plural or the singular form, there isn't a "better way" to go. It's up to you.

For registering a member, I found more appropriate this option

`POST /api/members`

because you're actually trying to create a new `member` resource.

As regards your last question, again is a matter of how you're imaging your `sign_in` resource. Is it meaningful that `sign_in` is a subresource of `members`? Before giving an answer, please pay attention to the trap enclosed in the type of resource you're describing. Are you sure you are *conceiving* the `sign_in` as a *thing* rather than an *action*?

Under this light, I believe that the `sign_in` resource would be more naturally placed under a different root.
However it's worth mentioning that signing in in REST is a bit tricky. Since the srever is not allowed to keep any session, you must be aware that *every* request *must* be authenticated (often via token). i don't want to go off topic, maybe you'll want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/319530/740480) before implementing your sign in mechanism.