# Form Based OAuth2 Resource Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to configure a **Spring Boot 1.5.0** application with **Spring Security OAuth2**, and my *userInfo server* is form-based. I have to send the *access_token* in a form-urlencoded way (not in a Header like "Authorization: Bearer ...").

Debugging in my IDE, I changed the *authorizationScheme* to "form", on **UserInfoRestTemplate** just like this example below:

[DefaultUserInfoRestTemplateFactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aToJ9.png)

It worked as I expected. The RestTemplate generated a "www-form-urlencoded", and the server responded with the user informations as I expected.

But now I'm not able to identify how do I make the change on *application.yaml* to make the same behaviour. I tryed some variations but without success (like this example below)

[application.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o77mK.png)

Anybody knows how's the correct way to set it up ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158864/2371309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: acme
      client-secret: acmesecret
      scope: read,write
      auto-approve-scopes: '.*'

facebook:
  client:
    clientId: 233668646673605
    clientSecret: 33b17e044ee6a4fa383f46ec6e28ea1d
    accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
    tokenName: oauth_token
    authenticationScheme: form
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  resource:
    userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com
```